# How to disable Mage cataloginventory observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, overrides

I'm using Magento 1.9.x, and I try to disable the original Mage cataloginventory observer.

So I edit my own extension `config.xml` like this:

```
<sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
    <observers>
          <inventory>
                <type>disabled</type>
          </inventory>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
```

But the original Mage observer is still active. How can I disable or maybe overwrite the `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php` with my own extension?

Comment: You're not showing the whole xml hierarchy, is `< sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>` in `<config><global><events>`? (It has to be in the same section (global/frontent etc) as the definition in `CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml`

Answer (score 2):

Configuration files are read in alphabetical order, if your own extension is loaded before the CatalogInventory configuration then your setting it overwritten and the observer stays active.
To have your configuration file loaded after after the CatalogInventory module,  you can add a `<depends>` tag in your module initialisation file in `app/etc/modules/` like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_ModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_CatalogInventory/>
            </depends>
        </Your_ModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick answer. I´ve already try to use the depends tags in my config file. But unfortunately that does not work. The oberserver is still active.

This is, how my module config file looks like:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Company_MyExtension>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Catalog />
            <Mage_CatalogInventory />
        </depends>
    </Company_MyExtension>
</modules>
</config>
```

Some other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you write your observer disabling declaration part in right scope, as in example you've given it should be in global scope

```
<global>
    <sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
            <observers>
                <inventory>
                    <type>disabled</type>
                </inventory>
            </observers>
    </sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
</global>
```